# C# MySql Parameterized Query makes longs into null

Tags: c#, mysql, parameterized

The code is based on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html

```
 public void TableTest(string connectionString)
    {
        string sqlToCreateTable = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table 
            (auction_key BIGINT NOT NULL, auction_owner VARCHAR(25),     first_seen BIGINT, 
            PRIMARY KEY(auction_key))";

        string sqlInsertOrUpdateAuction = "INSERT INTO my_table (auction_key)  VALUES (@my_auc_id); ";

        using (MySqlConnection dbConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            // is the table in the database?
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlToCreateTable, dbConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_auc_id", 123456);
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsertOrUpdateAuction, dbConnection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
    }
```

The error is that 123456 is seen as null.

Message=Column 'auction_key' cannot be null

I tried changing the "strict" setting in my.ini and it makes no difference.

Help please.

Comment: Thanks guys - putting the command before adding the parameters fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you add the parameter to the command and then instantiate a new command:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_auc_id", 123456);
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsertOrUpdateAuction, dbConnection);
```

If you do that, the command will no longer have the value for the @my_auc_id. Try switching those two lines:

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlInsertOrUpdateAuction, dbConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@my_auc_id", 123456);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could alleviate your issue, by simply doing the following:

```
using(var connection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection))
{
     connection.Open();
     using(var command = new MySqlCommand(createTableQuery, connection))
     {
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }

     using(var command = new MySqlCommand(insertOrUpdate, connection))
     {
          command.Parameters.Add("..", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int).Value = 123456;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Keep in mind that `ExecuteNonQuery` will return a zero or one, if it successfully worked.  Also you may want to manually specify the `SqlDbType`.  To avoid SQL inferring incorrectly.  Also, this will correctly scope your `MySqlCommand`, so you can correctly utilize for the queries.

And according to the documentation, it does implement the `IDisposable` to utilize the `using` block.  This ensures you instantiate your `MySqlCommand` again.